# Do fields have any effect besides MU (Mind Units)?

Tags: ingress

I know that in theory Mind Units are the point of the game as it's a score per side, but it really doesn't matter much on a regional scale.  Has anyone noticed any other affects that fields have for players?  Like maybe increased damage from xmps when attacking under friendly fields?  Or increased damage from enemy portals when attacking under enemy fields?

Comment: You know about the restrictions of creating links within fields?

Comment: Yep, knew that one, but thanks, worth noting for anyone else viewing the question.

Comment: @Sentry: No I don't. It sounds like that's an 'effect' that deserves to be in an answer no? What exactly is the restriction?

Comment: Dup of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158784/what-is-the-full-list-of-effects-that-fields-have

Answer (score 2):

It seems that linked portals give more items and more powerful ones when hacking them than unlinked ones.

Nothing seen when adding fields on the portal.

Comment: Interesting observation on the links.  I haven't noticed that but I'll keep an eye out.